# Can running an app from xcode on a phone cause the phone to have problems outside the app?

Tags: ios

I'm developing an app that I test on my phone (iPhone 7+, iOS 11).

After about an hour of using the app I find the phone develops a problem with the touchscreen - presses are registered in different areas of the screen - it's a small thing but it's enought to make using any app very frustrating.

I understood that the iOS infrastructure sandboxed everything, but it's entirely possible that this sealing only happens with apps that come from the app store.

Can anyone tell me theoretical or practical ways that this sort of intermitant fault could be occuring and good ways of investigating the source of the fault otherwise.

Comment: What does Instruments tell you?

Comment: As @matt suggests, I encourage you to profile your app using the Xcode quick profiling view (analyzing your app cpu/gpu/memory/disk usage) and also Instruments that gives you more details. Also, it depends of what kind of app you developed : it it has some special capabilities (background, GPS ...) then it might be tricky, even though iOS is supposed to take care of this, as any operating system would.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, easily! Via user defaults. Just make your app to write there something really big (couple megabytes) and then sync it and you will lock your phone so badly that will not be able to even power it off )

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open-ended question (I'm not sure it's suitable for SO).

But technically, if your phone is not jailbroken (~rooted), at best you can make it lag.

Either you'll make the software lag by overusing the CPU/GPU/memory, or overuse the bandwidth and have very little connectivity left for other apps (although that has not much to do with the phone).

So, the internet thing being a fake issue here, there is only the software lag that can happen. You can make that happen by saving large files on various threads, and simply doing many tasks that are very heavy.

But, that being said, the OS will always try to protect itself. If it's not having enough resources to keep itself alive, it'll start killing apps, and shoudl warn you a bit beforehand (see the `didReceiveMemoryWarning` in the `UIViewController` class). If the OS is close the the point where he needs resources, he'll start throwing warnings, and at some point it'll kill the app to free the resources.

Eventually it shouldn't lag anymore though. So my final answer should be

=> No, it can't.

Also, you're referring to some kind of hardware issue here, it seems a bit strange. I think it might be a coincidence.

I would suggest trying on simulators, see if you have the same kind of problems. And then trying on different devices, see if you endup "breaking" all those devices aswell. I'm pretty sure in both cases you won't and you're just unlucky, the devices kinda died on you or someone mishandled it.